# Will new automatically use swap if memory is limited?

Tags: c++, ram, swapfile

If I try to allocate memory:

```
int ramSize = magicLibrary.getRamSize();
assert(ramSize*2 <= pow(2,64-8));//Don't overflow the 64 bit limit (32 on some systems).

int * mainData new int[ramSize*2/sizeof(int)]; //2 times too big.
```

Will I get disk swap to fill in the space? If not, how can I use swap?

Comment: It's not really not this simple. Don't think about it and trust your operating system to work that out for you. :)

Comment: you will get an exception in some cases, or the an object that is created fine

Comment: Is your question really "how can I force a memory allocation to use swap", or "how can I force it not to?"  Because that's a little bit more straightforward than this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as neither RAM nor Swap-space is completely exhausted, and address space limitations (that is, 2-3GB in 32-bit, more than your ram in a 64-bit system), the system will allow you to allocate memory. If RAM is exhausted, the system will use swap-space.

Sometimes, the OS will also allow "overcommit", which is basically the same as airlines do when they "expect some passengers to not show up", so they sell a few extra tickets for that flight, and worry about "all seats full" when they get to that point. In terms of computers, that means that the OS may well allow you to allocate more memory than there really is available, and the error of "there isn't enough" is solved later by some means (typically by freeing up some memory that is "spare" or "killing some random application"). The reason the OS allows this is that applications quite often allocate large areas of memory that isn't fully used. Memory areas that are filled with zero may also be "merged" as "copy-on-write" memory, such that if you later write to it, it makes a new copy of that memory. This also may mean that if you allocate a large amount of memory, you have to actually write something (other than zero?) to it to make it "in use". Again, this reflects applications typical behaviour of "allocate a large amount of memory, fill it with zero, and only use some of it later" - so the OS tries to "save space" by not having a huge amount of "pages with just zeros in them".

Note that whether the memory is in RAM or Swap is a dynamic criteria - memory is swapped in and out all the time, and both program code and data may be swapped out at any time, and then be brought back when it's needed. It doesn't matter if this is "heap" or some other memory, all memory is pretty much equal in this respect.

It isn't entirely clear what you actually want to achieve, but hopefully this explains at least what happens.

Oh, and assuming `ramSize` is number of bytes, this is almost certainly always false:

```
assert(ramSize*2) <= 2^(64-8)
```

since `ramSize * 2 > 0`, and `(2 XOR 56) = 0`.

Comment: And even if `2^56` is supposed to mean `pow(2, 56)` we will have a hard time finding enough hard disks (tens of millions :-) to store the swap file.

Comment: I'm not aware of a 64-bit processor that allows more than `pow(2, 48)` of virtual address space, and that's actually `pow(2, 47)` on each side of "half the memory space" due to the requirement for "canonical" address - you can't have "some bits" of the top 16 bits set, so half the address has 0x0000 and the other has 0xffff in the top 16 bits.

Comment: Well, if you are a supercomputer you will run into the pow(2,48) limit :-), but I agree that for us the assert if meaningless except on 32-bit systems. Why do we need such a "canonical" requirement? Memory isn't floating point in which non-conical degrades precision.

Comment: The canonical requirement is to avoid "clever programmers sticking bits of data in unused part of the address" - this was discovered by Motorola in 1980-something, where some clever people used the upper 8 bits on 68000 (top 8 bits ignored in hw) as "object type indicators". Then the hardware people decided to use a 68020, and everything fell apart, since that processor uses the wHOLE 32-bits, and the upper bits caused the wrong memory address being used. So, by x86-64 rules, "all unused bits must be same as the top used bit", or the memory access fails for "non-canonical address".

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `new` knows nothing about swap. That's the job of the operating system (at least for general purpose operating systems, like the ones you are working with) and it will decide when to swap and what to swap out.

With that said, your attempt to allocate that much memory will almost certainly fail. Even if sufficient swap memory is available, the operating system reserves large chunks of *virtual address space* for itself which means what you can allocate is limited. For example, on 32-bit Windows 2GB of addresses are reserved for the kernel, and you coudln't allocate 4GB of virtual memory if you tried, because there aren't enough *addresses* available to represent that much memory.

What are you, actually, trying to do?

Comment: On top of a limited address space you will also run into address space fragmentation (at least on windows). In a typical 32 bit windows application the largest possible single allocation without using AWE, the /3GB boot.ini switch and/or rebasing dlls is around 1.2GB regardless of the amount of swap or memory the system has.

Comment: Certainly. The actual picture is a bit more complicated than the sketch in my answer. Thanks for adding a bit more context.

Answer (score 1):

In short Swap space is the portion of virtual memory that is on the hard disk, used when RAM is full. And this is the job of OS to take care of not the new operator!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `new`, the operating system receives a request for memory.
It then decides where to get that memory.

It is the same as with opening a file or echoing with cout. Those things are builtin to c++.

So your programms might already use swap, but you did not know about it.

If you want to know more about this subject, you might want to look up the inner workings of unix (mother and father of every operating system currently in use).